# How to compare two dataframes in python upon a span?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, bigdata

I have df1:

| S_A | S_B | S_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 80200797 | 81522815 | 2023-12-02 23:58:48 |
| 81601470 | 81308009 | 2023-12-02 23:58:48 |
| 81234864 | 81459304 | 2023-12-02 23:58:49 |

df2:

| M_A | M_B | M_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 87394727 | 89846725 | 2023-12-02 13:50:48 |
| 84729480 | 89573839 | 2023-12-02 20:27:32 |
| 89462844 | 89372944 | 2023-12-02 10:05:04 |

I am facing a challenge while working with two DataFrames, df1 and df2, containing large datasets of more than 3,200,000 and 2,500,000 rows, respectively. My goal is to extract a list of events from df1 that meet specific conditions related to another DataFrame, df2.

The conditions are as follows:

- I want to retrieve events from df1 where the values in the columns M_A and M_DT match those in S_A and fall within a time span defined by S_DT - 35s to S_DT - 20s. (M_B and S_B should be differ)
- Additionally, if there is a corresponding event in df2 with matching M_A in the specified time span and M_B different from S_B, I want to include the relevant information from df2 (specifically, the differing M_B).

I initially attempted to achieve this using an inner merge, but due to the large size of the DataFrames, it resulted in memory issues. Here is the code snippet I used:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on='S_A', right_on='M_A')
merged_df = merged_df[(merged_df['M_DT'] > (merged_df['S_DT'] - pd.Timedelta(seconds=35))) & 
                      (merged_df['M_DT'] < (merged_df['S_DT'] - pd.Timedelta(seconds=20)))]
```

Given the scale of the data, I suspect there might be a more memory-efficient approach to achieve the same result. Could someone provide guidance on optimizing this operation or suggest an alternative method to filter and extract the required information from these large DataFrames?

I am relatively new to working with such large datasets and would appreciate any assistance or guidance. Thank you!